# Is "I emphatically occupied the meeting room" correct usage?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

I want to mean that even though I wasn't supposed to be in the meeting room, I was still forcefully occupying it.

I am trying to use emphatic as an **adverb** but not sure if this is correct usage.

> *emphatically:*
>
> **adverb.**
> in a forceful way.

My friend pointed that *"she closed the door behind her emphatically"* is a different use-case

**UPDATE:**

What I am trying to imply is that even though I hadn't booked the meeting room, I was occupying it. I didn't leave until someone else who had actually booked the room asked me to.

So I used the room in an emphatic manner.

I understand I could use a better choice of words to describe this, but is this usage **incorrect?**

Comment: emphatically is usually applied to speech or gestures. However, literarily, I'd accept emphatically.

Comment: I think "deliberately" and "resolutely" come closer to the state you describe (i.e., just being in the room). However, you could emphatically defend your right to be in the room, or emphatically resist anyone who challenges you there or comes to remove you.

Comment: Intentionally, stubbornly, obstinately etc. may be better choice.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you mean. Did you use the room in an emphatic manner? Or are you emphatic about the fact that you used the room? They are different.

Comment: @WS2 good point, updated the question :)

Comment: But you used it in "an emphatic manner" (not "emphatically manner" - since that's an adverb). You could of course say you "used it emphatically". However, after all that, I am bound to say, as others have done - that whilst the meaning is fairly clear, "emphatic" is an unusual adjective to employ in this context, as @mahmudkoya points out.

Comment: Could you expand on the succession of events? The room was empty, and not booked, so you used it, until someone who had booked it for, say 13:00, came in at 12:55 and asked you to leave, which you did at 12:59? Or did you (other extreme case) go into an ongoing meeting at a booked time and did not leave until well into the next slot, and then only after being angrily accosted by the owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is incorrect, yes.

If you ‘**emphatically occupied the meeting room’ it would mean that you moved around in it a lot, in an emphatic way, making lots of gestures.**

I don’t think that that is what you mean to say!

‘Emphatic’ usually relates to a ‘*form of expression*’. It is the *expression* that is ‘emphatic’.

You could, however ‘be emphatic’ in your refusal to give the room to someone  else. As in:

‘My refusal to leave the room was emphatic’.

Note that here, we are again referring to ‘your expression’ your ‘refusal’ is ‘your expression’ - ie your gestures, speech etc, which, being ‘emphatic’ - are emphasised - meaning ‘forceful, exaggerated or larger than life’.

‘I emphatically refused to leave the room’ is also ok - note thst it is the *refusal* (the ‘expression’) that is emphatic.

Again, if you try to say ‘I used the room emphatically’ it is your ‘use of the room’ that is emphatic - so here we imagine you prancing about in the room theatrically, making overblown gestures and speaking loudly.

‘He was emphatic in his occupation of the meeting room’ does work - but again it is ‘his expression’ that is ‘emphatic’.

Another way of saying that you used the room forcibly might be:

‘I camped out in the room, without permission, emphatically refusing to allow others to enter’.

Or, ‘I subversively occupied the room without permission, emphatically fighting off any would-be intruders’.

Hope that helps!

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/emphatic